# Immer + Akkusativ?

Tags: adverb, accusative

Why is accusative used with `ein Pinguin` in the following sentence?

```
Man sollte immer einen Pinguin im Haus haben
```

Immer is an adverb, not a preposition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Immer** is simply an adverb and has no bearing as to case.

With **immer**, you're saying that one should **always** have a penguin in the house, without it, you're simply saying one should have a penguin in the house.

Akkusativ is used because *haben* is not a dative verb, and the penguin is the direct object, therefore it should be in the accusative case.  The noun *ein Pinguin* is masculine, therefore it is declined as such:

> Ich habe einen Pinguin
>
> Du hast einen Pinguin
>
> Er/sie/es hat einen Pinguin
>
> etc.

The only difference is the addition of the modal verb *sollen*.  Without it, you have this:

> Man hat einen Pinguin

Answer (score 5):

It does not depend on "immer" but on "sollte ... haben" (should have)

> Man sollte einen Pinguin im Haus haben.
>   Man sollte *{wen oder was?}* im Haus haben.

"immer" is just a nice add-on:
without "immer":

> Man sollte einen Pinguin im Haus haben.
>   You should have a penguin at home.

with "immer":

> Man sollte *immer* einen Pinguin im Haus haben.
>   You *always* should have a penguin at home.

Comment: so, do we always use akkusativ after all 6 modalverben , like sollen ?

Comment: @Özgür: No. It does not depend on the modal verb but on the full verb. If you use »helfen« instead of »haben« you have to use dative case: »Man sollte einem Pinguin helfen.« Without modal verb: »Man hat einen Pinguin.« (haben → accusative case) »Man hilft einem Pinguin.« (helfen → dative case)